# Container div does not expand to fit child div (without floats)

Tags: html, css

My container div does not expand to fit its child div - which has a top: 20px value.
I don't even have floats and have used both overflow:hidden (cuts part of the child div) or overflow:auto (creates scrollbars).

See codepen example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kadjia/pen/oxeOqJ)

```
<div class="container">
<div id="model">fdsf</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate any solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `top` and `position` properties and use `margin: 10px auto 0 auto;`

```
#model {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZEoPV)**

Comment: Thanks, I understand why margin works (as it is considered to be part of the element itself) but shouldn't the TOP attribute work as well?
what happens when you want to use LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM positions instead?

Comment: @Kadjia you are moving the element using `top` whereas using `margin-top` you are pushing the element.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In your example, the container is expanding to fit the child `div` correctly. The height of the child is 100px plus two times the border of 1px, in total 102px. Then, the height of the container is exactly 102px, as the developer tools in any browser can tell you.

Height of the contents totals 102px, thus the inner height of the container is 102px. This is by definition "expanding to fit the contents".

**2)** Now, you are setting `position: relative` for your child div. The following quote from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) should give a complete explanation to what is happening in your example.

Relative positioning:

> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not
>   positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on
>   table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption
>   elements is undefined.

**3)**
Obviously, you can get rid of this effect by getting rid of relative positioning, and just using `margin` instead. Regarding your comment, no, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` should absolutely not work. They are meant to be used for a totally different thing, for what the quote above explains.